# Convert time in AM / PM to minute after midnight format in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, how you convert time in AM / PM to minute after midnight format.
EG:- 1. 8:40 AM will be 520
     2. 9:00 PM will be 1260

Thanks

Comment: what type is your column in MySQL? If it's DateTime, the following should work: DATE_FORMAT(date_time, "%k") * 60 + DATE_FORMAT(date_time, "%i")

Comment: It's not good at all. Either add DateTime column, or it would be much more easier to perform this task using programming language (not in SQL). Of course you can create a stored procedure for doing this using MySQL, but this would be an overkill, and it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert the string to a date with `STR_TO_DATE()`, then do the calculation with `HOUR()` and `MINUTE()` functions:

```
SELECT HOUR(STR_TO_DATE('8:40 AM', '%l:%i %p')) * 60 +
  MINUTE(STR_TO_DATE('8:40 AM', '%l:%i %p')) AS minutes
```

Results in:

```
minutes
---------
520
```

And ...

```
SELECT HOUR(STR_TO_DATE('9:00 PM', '%l:%i %p')) * 60 +
  MINUTE(STR_TO_DATE('9:00 PM', '%l:%i %p')) AS minutes
```

Results in:

```
minutes
---------
1260
```